# Resorting integers in PHP to remove gaps

Tags: php

I'm searching for an algorithm to remove gaps between numbers. Example of my problem:

Here is a range of integers: [1,2,3,4,9,10,11,17...]

I need to make those numbers like this: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8...]

Can anyone provide me with a working example of PHP code to obtain such a result?

Comment: That is not “sorting” in the first place …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should fetch min and max from an array and create the range,

```
$min = min($arr);
$max = max($arr);
print_r(range($min,$max));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make by using `range` function as:

// given array 2,4,6 and 9 are missing.

```
$arr1 = array(1,3,5,7,8,10);
```

// construct a new array using `range` function by giving `min(given array)` and `max(given array)` value

```
$arr2 = range(min($arr1),max($arr1));
```